# How to reorder table rows (drag-and-drop) along with their sub rows

Tags: javascript, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table which looks like this (simplified for the example):

```
<table>
<tr class="lvl_1">
    <td>
    Level 1
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="lvl_2">
    <td>
    Level 2
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="lvl_3">
    <td>
    Level 3
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="lvl_1">
    <td>
    Level 1
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="lvl_2">
    <td>
    Level 2
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="lvl_3">
    <td>
    Level 3
    </td>
</tr>
```

The content in the rows with the lvl_3 class are children of the previous lvl_2 row, and the lvl_2 rows are children of the previous lvl_1.

Had the data been a list, it would have looked something like this:

```
Level 1
-- Level 2
---- Level 3
Level 1
-- Level 2
---- Level 3
```

I'm now looking to implement drag-and-drop sorting functionality, make it possible to rearrange the level 1 and two rows. The tricky part is that once I start moving a row, the corresponding children (and grand-children, if any) should move along with it.

Is this even possible with the current markup, or do I have to rearrange the code?

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear why you are not using UL LI lists for achieving this. You can i believe use jQuerys some of remove and append functions to easily implement this

Comment: Because, as I mentioned, the example is simplified. In the actual scenario, each row contains several columns and is, indeed, tabular data.